# How to concatenate Date value to string in a formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to concatenate today's date into a formula that will be added to a cell.

On the line

```
Cells(2, colNum).Value = "=AVERAGE(Table57[" & today & " Avg Vuln Sev Score])
```

I get an error message

> run time error 1004: application-defined or object defined error

I tried formatting the Date in various ways but everything is returning an error. 
I tried:

- using + instead of &
- wrapping it in TEXT()
- wrapping it with the Format()
- throwing Date directly in there with & Date &
- ActiveSheet.Cells(2, colNum).Value =

All of it throws errors.

I'm trying to get it to work in a `=AVERAGE(Table57[" & Date & " Avg Vuln Sev Score])` format.

```vb
Sub TREG()

    Dim lnRow As Long, lnCol As Long
    Dim colNum

    colNum = WorksheetFunction.Match("Findings Variance (4/15 vs Current)", ActiveSheet.Range("1:1"), 0)
    Columns(colNum).Select

    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Cells(1, colNum).Value = "(Scan date) Findings Total"
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Cells(1, colNum).Value = "(Scan date) AVG Vuln SevScore"

    Dim today As String
    today = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    Cells(2, colNum).Value = "=AVERAGE(Table57[" & today & " Avg Vuln Sev Score])"

End Sub
```

Comment: What errors are being thrown?

Comment: "run time error 1004: application-defined or object defined error" is the most common one. i looked into it and the only thing i was able to find is that VBA wants the workbook/sheet specified as the cause of that error. i tried adding the "ActiveSheet." to the Cells().Value but no luck

Comment: `Debug.Print "=AVERAGE(Table57[" & today & " Avg Vuln Sev Score])"` - is it what you expect? What should it be?

Comment: Run time error 1004 is a named range error. It might be to do with the table. Can you use cell references instead?

Comment: yes, the final look would be "=AVERAGE(Table57[ 2/12/2020 Avg Vuln Sev Score])" (2/12/2020 changing to whatever today's date is when its run)

Comment: Should it be `02/12/2020` or `2/12/2020` - there's a difference. Also, I'd use `.Formula` instead of `.Value`. But `.Formula = "=AVERAGE(Table57[" & Date & " Avg Vuln Sev Score])"` works for me.

Comment: no luck with .Formula = "=AVERAGE(Table57[" & Date & " Avg Vuln Sev Score])" still getting the 1004 error. its very weird

Comment: Is there a space before the date? `.Formula = "=AVERAGE(Table57[ " & Date & " Avg Vuln Sev Score])"`?

Comment: as for 02/12/2020 or 2/12/2020, at this point whichever will get it to work is what i'll go with

Comment: yes, it's copy/pasted from your comment

Comment: So `.Formula = "=AVERAGE(Table57[ " & Date & " Avg Vuln Sev Score])"`... does not work? Note the space after the first bracket. Whenever you can't get a formula to work, `Debug.Print` the output, and copy it from the Immediate Window into your worksheet to verify that it's correct.

Comment: that solved it! thank you. I had to add another space between the " =AVERAGE and that solved it